# How can i get handle for separate windows using MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm new to MFC. Can anyone please tell me how can I get handle separate windows using MFC. My task is to take screenshot of separate windows and I want to display it. By using `CWnd::GetDesktopWindow` I’ll take the handle for desktop. If I want to get handle for other windows how can I get it. Now i got the handle for desktop if I want to display the desktop which I captured how I can do it. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what types of window do you want to get. To retrieve some window has specified class name or caption, please use API FindWindow(...) with class&caption as input; to get all the child windows under desktop or some top level window, you could use EnumWindows(...) in a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the handle to all the windows on your desktop, you need the function [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You provide it with a callback function and it will call it with a handle to each window it finds.

To get an MFC `CWnd*` from a `HWND`, you can do this:

```
CWnd *const window = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
```